# Evaluating $\int_{|z|=1} \sin\left(e^{\frac{1}{z}}\right)  \ dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

Let

$$\int_{|z|=1} \sin\left(e^{\frac{1}{z}}\right) dz.$$

Is there an alternative to the residue theorem if we want to calculate the above integral?

Comment: Change variables $w=\frac{1}{z}$ and see things simplify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sasha posted a terse comment suggesting the same substitution I was about to suggest.  Here's why that's a good idea: the exponential function behaves in a messy way at $\infty$, and $1/z=\infty$ at a point that's inside the circle $|z|=1$.  "Messy" means an essential singularity rather than a pole.  After this substitution, the zero in the denominator is no longer in the exponential function.  The singularity at $z=0$ is at $w=\infty$, and that point is not inside the curve you'll integrate along.

So $z=1/w$, $dz=\text{what?}$.

Then as $z$ moves along the curve $|z|=1$, what path does $w$ follow?